# Normalizr change the original file .json or generate a new file .json with the schema desired?

Tags: json, normalizr

If I use normalizr for the file .json the original file change or not ? Or just a new file .json is create with the new schema defined with normalizr?

Answer (score 0):

Normalizr does not overwrite the input data. Instead, it returns a new object.

If you want to overwrite a file, you'll need to pass the normalized response back through node's `fs.write` or `fs.writeFile` or similar.